# Rails: Why does custom url change when `render 'new'` is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, url-routing

I have a controller that controls a contact us form on a contact page. Inside the `routes.rb` file I have a line that says `match '/contact', :to => 'feedback#new'`. Now when the form is filled out correctly, everything works fine; the url is '/contact'. However, when the form isn't filled out correctly, my controller `renders 'new'` and the url changes from `'/contact'` to `'/feedback'`. Can someone tell me why this happens and how I can fix it so that if the validations are triggered and the page is rendered, the url will be `/contact` still and not `/feedback`? Thanks!

My controller code:
[image]

Comment: Can you list the contents of your `config/routes.rb` file? [Edit] The view code would help, too. If you're using `form_for(@feedback)`, when the form posts, it's doing a POST to `/feedback` since Rails uses RESTful URLs. Remember that URLs are based on routes to controllers and actions, NOT the name of the view you're rendering. `FeedbackController#create` is likely mapped to `/feedback` (check `rake routes`)

Comment: You're right `FeedbackController#create` is mapped to the `/feedback` route. So what should I do to answer my above question?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am struggling with this.

Comment: @skaz - Yes and no. I found that if you set the title in the create action of your controller, when render is called, the url will still be set to what you want; however, I am not sure if this is how it is suppose to be done, or if it's just a quick fix. I still do not know why this happens.

Comment: I am setting @title in my create but it still isn't helping.  Can you provide any code?  Thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 10):

```
match '/contact', :to => 'feedback#new'
```

That route will only match `/contact` to `FeedbackController#new`.

You will want to add to match the "post" part to `FeedbackController#create`

```
match '/contact', :to => 'feedback#create', :via => :post, :as => :post_contact
# change :as => to whatever path for this you'd like to use, ex :as => :create_contact
```

Your form will now change to

```
= form_for(@feedback), :url => post_contact_path do |f|
```

Just using the default `form_for` will try to create the path from a `resources` in your `routes.rb`. And, i'm assuming that route is `resources :feedback` which will of course create routes that look like `/feedback`.

Comment: Just FYI, I had to add `:via => :get` to the #new path in Rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

in your routes.rb instead of your `/contact` matcher use:

```
resources :contact, :as => :feedback, :controller => :feedback, :only => [:new, :create]
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes